# How to get for() number

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script

Well all I really need is for a certain number to increase every time a for loop is completed. Here is my code:

```
function TEST(){
for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
var test = 1
test++
Logger.log(test)
}
```

but the logger output only looks like:

```
[14-02-24 17:53:19:100 PST] 2.0
[14-02-24 17:53:19:100 PST] 2.0
[14-02-24 17:53:19:100 PST] 2.0
[14-02-24 17:53:19:100 PST] 2.0
```

How can I resolve this? Thanks is probably just me not thinking correctly about for() loops :P

** SOLVED **

What I found is that you could just do

```
var test = i
```

hehe how silly of me :-)

Comment: It may be beneficial to read the contents of your for loop out loud. This may pinpoint where the problem may be so you can resolve it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Declare your test variable outside the for loop. Otherwise, it keeps resetting to 1 when you iterate the loop.

```
function TEST(){
    var test = 1
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        test++
        Logger.log(test)
    }
}
```